# Como mostrar datos entre dos fechas desde PHP y JSON

Tags: php, json, postgresql

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de mostrar dos fechas desde mi web service en php y me arroja error el codigo

este es mi query:

```
select * from ventas where fecha between ? and ?
```

este es mi codigo de php (cabe mencionar que lo intente con GET y POST)

codigo php GET:

```
<?php
require 'SQLGlobal.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    try{
        $fechauno = $_GET['fechauno'];
        $fechados = $_GET['fechados'];
        $respuesta = SQLGlobal::selectArrayFiltro(
            "select * from ventas where fecha between ? and ?",
            array($fechauno,$fechados)
        );//con filtro ("El tamaño del array debe ser igual a la cantidad de los '?'")
        echo json_encode(array(
            'respuesta'=>'200',
            'estado' => 'Se obtuvieron los datos correctamente',
            'data'=>$respuesta,
            'error'=>''
        ));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'respuesta'=>'-1',
                'estado' => 'Ocurrio un error, intentelo mas tarde',
                'data'=>'',
                'error'=>$e->getMessage())
        );
    }
}
```

?>

codigo php POST:

```
<?php
require 'SQLGlobal.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    try{
        $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);


        $fecha = $datos["fecha"];
        $respuesta = SQLGlobal::selectArrayFiltro(
            "select * from ventas where fecha between ? and ?",
            array($fecha)
        );//con filtro ("El tamaño del array debe ser igual a la cantidad de los '?'")
        echo json_encode(array(
            'respuesta'=>'200',
            'estado' => 'Se obtuvieron los datos correctamente',
            'data'=>$respuesta,
            'error'=>''
        ));
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'respuesta'=>'-1',
                'estado' => 'Ocurrio un error, intentelo mas tarde',
                'data'=>'',
                'error'=>$e->getMessage())
        );
    }
}
```

?>

como se pueden dar cuenta despues de hacer la consults los datos obtenidos los ingreso en un JSON sin embargo no se si sera ese el problema

con GET mi pagina no carga

aparece el mensaje de que no funciona por el momento

pero con POST me arroja el siguiente mensaje al usar una pagina llamada reqBIN que sirve para poder probar los JSON e insertando el sig JSON

```
{ "fecha":"'01-01-2022'","fecha":"'01-01-2023'" }
```

mensaje de error con post

`{"respuesta":"-1","estado":"Ocurrio un error, intentelo mas tarde","data":"","error":"SQLSTATE[08P01]:
>: 7 ERROR: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement \"pdo_stmt_00000001\" requires 2"}`

no se si puedan ayudarme, espero que si gracias..

Comment: ¿Desde dónde envías los datos al servidor: un formulario, una URL...? Muestra ese contexto, si vas a mandar dos fechas, no puedes etiquetarlas ambas con el nombre `fecha`, porque luego ¿cómo vas a diferenciar cuál es cual? Debes mandarlas con `name` distintos, o mandar un array o algo así. Pon un `var_dump($_GET);` y/o un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Método Post, claramente dice que solo un parámetro está recibiendo:
El objeto JSON que estás pasando tiene duplicado el nombre "fecha"

```
{ "fecha":"'01-01-2022'","fecha":"'01-01-2023'" }
```

Corrige la llamada y cambia los nombres de las propiedades del JSON, y el formato de las fechas para ser YYYY-MM-DD

```
{ "fecha1":"'2022-01-01'","fecha2":"'2023-01-01'" }
```

Luego podrías hacer algo similar:

```
$fecha1 = $datos["fecha1"];
$fecha2 = $datos["fecha2"];
$respuesta = SQLGlobal::selectArrayFiltro(
            "select * from ventas where fecha between ? and ?",
            array($fecha1, $fecha2);
```

Comment: Hola @DEVX75 , gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responderme, ya intente hacer lo que me dices y sigue sin funcionar ahora marca este error  **HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**. estuve leyendo en internet y al parecer mi problema es porque JSON no es capaz de leer los datos de tipo Date ya que no tiene formato especifico, no se si sea cierto eso y haya una forma de utilizar el tipo de dato, es que apenas comencé a trabajar con los JSON

Comment: Luis Ángel, el tema es que las fechas, según indicas, es que tienen formato dd-mm-aaaa y para asociarlo a un parámetro Fecha me imagino que requiere el formato aaaa-mm-dd. No puedo asegurártelo porque no conozco si esa comprobación la hace la clase SQLGlobal, pero tiene toda la pinta.
Conviene transformarlos una vez recibidos (si el formato no es el correcto) antes de pasarlos como parámetros al filtro. Prueba y al menos ya no tendrás ese problema.

Comment: Lo que menciona @VFG es correcto, para tal efecto debes usar el formato YYYY-MM-DD entre comillas simples, las cuales ya tienes, solo formatea la fecha correctamente antes de incluirla al JSON. Respuesta actualizada